# Membership edit screen defaulting membership dates to 12/31/1969?

Tags: civimember, joomla

I recently updated from CiviCRM 5.5(.2?) to 5.14.1, and now if I go to edit the membership record for a contact (or add a new membership record), the Member Since, Membership Start Date, and Membership End Date fields all show 12/31/1969. I can put correct dates in there and save the record just fine, but for an existing membership that I'm editing, it should (and used to) show the dates that are currently stored in the database, and which show up correctly on the contact's Membership tab.

I'm running it under Joomla 3.8.12 with PHP 7.1.1 on IIS 7.5. Honestly, I have no idea where to even start looking to figure out what the heck is going on.

Has anyone else seen this, or have any suggestions on where to start?

Comment: Hi Roy and welcome to civicrm stack exchange. Do you have logging on - System Admin -> Misc -> Logging if so there will be a record of changes for each database table in another table called log_civicrm_*.  If you are familar with mysql you should check out log_civicrm_membership. Do you have a pre upgrade database backup?